# How to add active class to link which is loaded via views and links comes from content type

Tags: 7, navigation

1. I have created a content type calls as "XYZ Inner Pages".
2. Here I am adding a Fieldset and inside field set I am adding field type as Link.
3. Now I create a page using XYZ "Inner Pages" Content Type, add content and the links.
4. I am hiding the Links from Manage display because I want to show those on the right side of page.
5. Now I am creating a view which will pull all the links from "XYZ Inner Pages" Content Type.
6. Now I am showing the views block in the right section of "XYZ Inner Pages" Content Type page.
7. This right block will list the link.
8. Now I want to add active class to links so when I open any of the link from that list, then opened link from the list should be highlighted.

Comment: You can do it with jQuery and check if the current page url = the link url. If yes, add the active class.

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to do the same but is there any other way to do? I wanted to avoid jQuery.

Comment: Now that I thought more about it, probably with a preprocress function.

Comment: I am bit new in Drupal. Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: What Drupal version are you using 7 or 8?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7

Comment: I gotta go now. I'll give it a shot tomorrow if no one has answered it by then.

Comment: You are using the contrib [Link](https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/link-7.x-1.4.tar.gz) module right?

Comment: Yes. I am using Link module

Answer (score 1):

Example:

In my content type I added a link field called "link", so the machine name is `field_link`

In this link field for url I put http://example.com/node/3

I created a View called "Test".

In fields I added link.

In fields I added link again, but this time I change the formatter to `URL, as plain text`

[image]

We are going to use [template_preprocess_views_view_fields](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7.x-3.x)

In your theme's **template.php** file you add

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

  if ($vars['view']->name == "test"){

    $field_link = strip_tags($vars['fields']['field_link_1']->content); // use strip_tags function to remove HTML markup.
    $field_link = str_replace('http://', '', $field_link); // remove http://
    $field_link = str_replace('www.', '', $field_link); // remove www.

    $node_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . request_path(); // see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/request_path/7.x

    if ($field_link == $node_url){

      $vars['fields']['field_link']->content = '<div class="active-link">' . $vars['fields']['field_link']->content . '</div>';

    }

    $vars['fields']['field_link_1']->content = null; // hides the field_link_1 field

  }

}
```

- replace **mytheme** with the actual name of your theme.
- replace **test** with the actual name of your view.
- replace **field_link** with the actual name of your field.

Then you add the CSS to your theme's style.css file, Example:

```
.active-link a { color: green; }
```

Comment: Remember to flush/clear the cache to see changes.

Comment: yes sure. Will get back to you soon.

Comment: @ManjiriLimaye you're welcome, please accept the answer by clicking the ✅ checkmark, thx